# How to unit test vim function in vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I have functions inside my .vimrc file and want to test that this function is doing what I want it to do. I want to know if there is a rapid way to unit test a function within .vimrc.

my function looks like:

```
fun! FindPythonMainFile(filename, )
    let file = findfile(filename)  
      if (file)
         echo "file exists"
      else
         echo "file doesn't exists"
     endif

endf
```

best regard.

Comment: https://github.com/junegunn/vader.vim See https://github.com/embear/vim-localvimrc/tree/master/test as an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would do is moving these functions out of your `.vimrc` into separate [`autoload-functions`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#autoload-functions). You'll get additional benefits like unique namespaces, less clutter, faster Vim startup, and these can (still) be invoked from anywhere (mappings, commands, unit tests).

For a minimal, roll-your-own test, just invoke the function and make assertions. Your function as given would be hard to test, as its side effect is the `:echo`, and you'd have to do a cumbersome `:redir` or `execute()` to capture it. It would be better to split this into the actual check (that returns a Boolean) and a separate reporting function with the `:echo`s.

To notify yourself of the test results, you can just `:echo` any errors / results, or abort with `:cquit`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56054542/813602) for using Vim's built-in `assert_...()` functions to make assertions and minimal reporting.

I don't think many people test their own personal customizations (but I applaud you for attempting to do that!) For plugins (that you may intend to publish to others), this is a different matter. Multiple approaches and frameworks exist there, so it may be worth to evaluate those if you intend to go that direction. My [runVimTests plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2565) is one such framework (that I use to test dozens of my plugins); the plugin page has links to alternatives.

Comment: UT has moved to github: https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-UT

Comment: @LucHermitte: Thanks for mentioning; I've updated my reference.